# GET multiselect selected values

Tags: laravel, request, multi-select

I need to get the multiselect selected values:

With a simple select work fine with this method:

```
public function championships(Request $request)
{
   $nationId = $request->get('q');
   return Championship::where('nation_id', $nationId)->get(['id', 'name as text']);
}
```

But I need to getall the selected values in the multiselect and pass it to the query using an array with the whereIn.

But I do not know how to capture the values of the multiselect

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want multiselect you must tell laravel it is an array of values what that select box is about. You do that by appending "[]" to the name of the select box.

```
<select name="q[]">
```

Now, when the controller retrieves the value of this input, it will be in the form of an array, instead of an scalar value.

So, for the sake of clarity in your code, it should be like this:

```
$nationIds = $request->get('q');
```

And now you want to choose from an array of values, not a single one, so now you need a "whereIn", instead of "where":

```
return Championship::whereIn('nation_id',$nationIds)->get(['id', 'name as text']);
```

Comment: yep, this how u do it :D

Comment: that's what I had tried, but the $ request-> get ('q'); It only returns a single value. The multiselect ``<select class="form-control {{$class}}" style="width: 100%;" name="{{$name}}[]" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="{{ $placeholder }}" {!! $attributes !!} >``

Answer (score -1):

Try this following.

```php
Championship::select('id', 'name as text')->where('nation_id', $nationId)->get();
```

And where statement

```php
$users = Championship::select('id', 'name as text')
->where([
    ['nation_id', '=', $nationId],
    ['name', 'like', $name],
])->get();
```

Or where statement

```php
$users =Championship::select('id', 'name as text')
    ->where('nation_id', '=', $nationId)
    ->orWhere('name', 'like', $name)
    ->get();
```